# Julia - Reshaping an array according to a vector

Tags: julia, reshape

I have an array of arrays, a

```
49455-element Array{Array{AbstractString,1},1}
```

the length varies, this is just one of many possibilities

I need to do a b = vcat(a...) giving me

```
195158-element Array{AbstractString,1}:
```

and convert it to a SharedArray to have all cores work on the strings in it (I'll convert to a Char matrix behind the curtians, but this is not important)

In a, every element is an array of some number of strings, which I do

```
map(x -> length(x), a)
49455-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  4
  8
  .
  .
  2
```

Is there a way I can easily resotre the array b to the same dimensions of a?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the Iterators.jl package:

```
# `a` holds original. `b` holds flattened version. `newa` should == `a`

using Iterators            # install using Pkg.add("Iterators")
lmap = map(length,a)       # same length vector defined in OP

newa = [b[ib+1:ie] for (ib,ie) in partition([0;cumsum(lmap)],2,1)]
```

This is somewhat neat, and can also be used to produce a generator for the original vectors, but a `for` loop implementation should be just as fast and clear.

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to Dan Getz's answer, we can also use `zip` instead of Iterators.jl's `partition`:

```
tails = cumsum(map(length,a))
heads = [1;tails+1][1:end-1]
newa = [b[i:j] for (i,j) in zip(heads,tails)]
```

Comment: Did you try this with longer than length 1 vectors?

Comment: @DanGetz  `cumsum` is what i was looking for. just so sloppy at midnight ;)